# Maven: Could not resolve archetype

Tags: java, maven

I get this error when I try to create a webapp maven project.

Here is the entire error message.

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:RELEASE from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:RELEASE
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Osvaldo\.m2\repository)
Failed to resolve version for org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:RELEASE: Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\Osvaldo\.m2\repository)
```

Here is some workarounds I have tried to do:

1. Delete `C:\Users\XXXX\\.m2\repository` and run `MAVEN -> UPDATE MAVEN`
2. Edit the maven `settings.xml` unactivating any proxies. Above the part of the file:

   ```
   <proxy>
       <id>XXXX</id>
       <active>**false**</active>
       <protocol>http</protocol>
       <!-- US Proxies -->
       <host>172.20.100.5</host>
       <port>8080</port>
   </proxy>
   ```
3. Doublecheck the reference of settings.xml at eclipse

   `Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings`
4. Adding remote maven catalog manually

   `Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Archetypes`

Comment: Can you share when this message occurs? And how your pom.xml is configured?

Comment: This error occurs when I try to create a new webapp maven project. So there is no pom.xml file yet

Comment: Then what is the commandline that you use to generate the archetype?

Comment: Actually I'm creating using the Eclipse interface.
I'm using these options:
maven-archetype-webapp
Groupid - br.com
Artifac name - projectname
0.0.1 Snapshot
Package - war